# Debug sklearn using vscode

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have sklearn installed in anconda, I need to debug the sklearn to follow some functionality and understand how some things are happening behind the scene

I used vscode to debug python, once in a flask app, but in this case of sklearn and anaconda I was not able to do the same.

If there anyway to do that?

Thanx all!